# Adding new elements to an object

Tags: python

I am working with a polynomial program that takes in termpairs like this where the inputs are (coefficient, exponent)

P1 = Polynomial((9, 11), (6, 14), (-12, 3), (42, 0))

Here is my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, *termpairs):
        L = [x for x in termpairs]
        L = sorted(L, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        self.coeffs = L
```

So my question is how can I add another term to the already made object? The new term is added like this P1.addterm(coefficient, exponent) and heres what I have so far and it doesn't work:

```
def addterm(self, *newterm):
        for i in range(len(self.coeffs)):
            if self.coeffs[i][1] == newterm[1]:
                #code for when exponent is already in polynomial 
                break
            else:
                self.coeffs = Polynomial(self.coeffs), newterm)
                break
```

Comment: Note that `L = [x for x in termpairs]` is equivalent to `L = termpairs[:]` but you have no reason to create a shallow copy here, because `sorted` does that anyway - so simply pass `termpairs` to `sorted` directly.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to sort by exponent instead of coefficient?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like all your terms are just tuple elements in a list `self.coeffs`. In which case....

```
def addterm(self, newcoeff, newexp):
    newterm = (newcoeff, newexp)
    self.coeffs.append(newterm)
    self.coeffs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # operator.itemgetter is probably better here.
    # # self.coeffs.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: This definitely works, but sorting the whole list when you want to insert one element in order seems wasteful.

Comment: @timgeb agreed, but similarly `bisect` and `list.insert` seem unnecessarily complex and worst-case more expensive than `append` and `sort`.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that `bisect` is worse than `sort` here? (I think we care about the average case.)

Comment: @timgeb: Although it's not related to the complexity of each method, no function in the `bisect` module accepts a `key` parameter, which makes it a lot less versatile than `.sort()`.

Comment: @timgeb It may be more familiarity than anything. My gut says not to import another module for a best-case incredibly small performance increase that will detract from code readability (I know exactly what `append` `sort` does, but `bisect.insort` is less obviously correct for someone who doesn't know the module, and `bisect_left` -> `insert` is less obviously correct for someone new to the approach). If this was a performance bottleneck, it'd be the first optimization I reached for!

Comment: That said, I also can't think of a time I used `bisect` in production code, so I may just be too noob to write good code ;)

Answer (score 2):

`self.coeffs` is a list, so just append onto the end of it and re-sort the list:

```
self.coeffs.append(newterm)
self.coeffs.sort(key=lambda p: p[1])
```

Note that your function signature is wrong if you indeed want to pass in a single tuple. Remove the `*` and it will work as intended.

If you swap the order of your data and store `(exponent, coefficient)` instead of `(coefficient, exponent)`, you can also use the `bisect` module to avoid sorting:

```
import bisect

...

bisect.insort(self.coeffs, newterm)
```